# How do I convert the items in a list from integers to '.' and ' '?

Tags: python

I have this code that works for the integers in my list

```
def draw_beautiful(n):
    ps = list(gen(n))
    max = len(' '.join(map(str,ps[-1])))
    for p in ps:
        print(' '.join(map(str,p)).center(max)+'\n')
```

the list is generated like pascals triangle, but every odd is a 1 and every even is a 0.

```
def gen(n,r=[]):
    for x in range(n):
        l = len(r)
        r = [1 if i == 0 or i == l else (r[i=1]+r[i])%2 for i in range(l+1)]
        yield r
```

as is, it prints a nice triangle made of ones and zeros, but I need the ones to be dots and the zeros to be spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `draw_beautiful`, try replacing

```
ps = list(gen(n))
```

by

```
ps = [[' .'[x] for x in row] for row in gen(n)]
```

This will turn `0` to `' '` and `1` to `'.'`.

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be intergers, not list

Comment: ps = [[' .'[x] for x in row] for row in gen(n)] worked; could you explain what the ' .'[x] specifically does?

Comment: @AndrewYoung: `" ."` is a string, and strings are numerically indexed sequences, so assuming `x` is an int in `(0, 1)`, `" ."[x]` will yield either the first (empty string) or second (dot) character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to change the values in the list

```
p = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
o = []

for x in p:
    if x == 1:
        o.append('.')
    if x == 0:
        o.append(' ')
```

Comment: OH that makes sense. thank you very much I'll give it a shot

Comment: @AndrewYoung are you running the code above just as is or have you altered it?